# Can I reuse clauses in Resolution Method?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was doing an exercise on the Resolution Method, and I ended up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ8ay.jpg)

Is the purple part allowed? Since {s} not only has already been used, it also was used to create {~s}.

I think it is allowed, but I'm not sure, and would like to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using the same clause multiple times is not only allowed, but sometimes absolutely necessary in order to be able to get to the empty clause.

In your particular case, you can actually avoid multiple uses: instead of resolving the $\{ q, \neg s \}$ clause with $\{s\}$ to get $\{ q \}$, and then resolving that with $\{ \neg q, \neg s \}$ to get $\{ \neg s \}$, you can resolve $\{ q, \neg s \}$ and $\{ \neg q, \neg s \}$ to immediately get $\{ \neg s \}$ in just one step.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason resolution is possible is because of [cut-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem).

The cut rule in the [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) essentially tells allows us to reuse the same lemma multiple times in a proof. Cut-elimination says that a proof using cut can be turned into a (longer) proof without cut, which is crucial for resolution because the procedure only finds cut-free proofs.

So this gives an intuitive reason why we may need to reuse a clause multiple times in a resolution proof.